# Is it better to use dimens files or create multiple layouts to support multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android, layout, dimension, screen-size

I'm about to publish my app and I'm confused between using multiple dimension files and using multiple layouts or is there any other way so my app can support multiple screen sizes.

I would really appreciate your help on this one!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this implementation for different screen sizes in DP

> https://github.com/intuit/sdp

and implementation for different screen sizes in SP

> https://github.com/intuit/ssp

Comment: Thanks! It's gonna be much easier to use this implementation, but are you sure it works on all android phones?